# Problem: Bob's Sale

Tags: algorithm

*Note: this is an abstract rewording of a real-life problem regarding ordering records in a SWF file. A solution will help me improve an open-source application.*

Bob has a store, and wants to do a sale. His store carries a number of products, and he has a certain integer quantity of units of each product in stock. He also has a number of shelf-mounted price labels (as many as the number of products), with the prices already printed on them. He can place any price label on any product (unitary price for one item for his entire stock of that product), however some products have an additional restriction - any such product may not be cheaper than a certain other product.

You must find how to arrange the price labels, such that the total cost of all of Bob's wares is as low as possible. The total cost is the sum of each product's assigned price label multiplied by the quantity of that product in stock.

---

Given:

- N – the number of products and price labels
- S<sub>*i*</sub>, 0≤*i*<N – the quantity in stock of product with index *i* (integer)
- P<sub>*j*</sub>, 0≤*j*<N – the price on price label with index *j* (integer)
- K – the number of additional constraint pairs
- A<sub>*k*</sub>, B<sub>*k*</sub>, 0≤*k*<K – product indices for the additional constraint

  - Any product index may appear at most once in B. Thus, the graph formed by this adjacency list is actually a set of directed trees.

The program must find:

- M<sub>*i*</sub>, 0≤*i*<N – mapping from product index to price label index (P<sub>M<sub>*i*</sub></sub> is price of product *i*)

To satisfy the conditions:

1. P<sub>M<sub>A<sub>*k*</sub></sub></sub> ≤ P<sub>M<sub>B<sub>*k*</sub></sub></sub>, for 0≤*k*<K
2. Σ(S<sub>*i*</sub> × P<sub>M<sub>*i*</sub></sub>) for 0≤*i*<N is minimal

---

Note that if not for the first condition, the solution would be simply sorting labels by price and products by quantity, and matching both directly.

Typical values for input will be N,K<10000. In the real-life problem, there are only several distinct price tags (1,2,3,4).

---

Here's one example of why most simple solutions (including topological sort) won't work:

You have 10 items with the quantities 1 through 10, and 10 price labels with the prices $1 through $10. There is one condition: the item with the quantity 10 must not be cheaper than the item with the quantity 1.

The optimal solution is:

```
Price, $   1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
Qty        9  8  7  6  1 10  5  4  3  2
```

with a total cost of $249. If you place the 1,10 pair near either extreme, the total cost will be higher.

Comment: What happens if you topological sort the items, with quantity as a "tie-breaker". Then match with prices. Does that give an optimal/good-enough solution?

Comment: The first condition doesn't allow arbitrary reordering of price tags. Some products *must not* be cheaper than others. **EDIT**: haven't thought about topological sorting

Comment: Huh?  All the price tags are already printed, and the number of them is equal to the number of products.  Therefore the total cost of products is constant regardless of which product has which price tag.  Can you re-express your question.  Your notation is confusing to somebody adept at algorithms and problem solving but lacks experience in formal mathematical notation.

Comment: I don't think topological sorting is going to be enough. The case breaking most simple solutions would be one where you have 1000 items of a product that *must* be more expensive than a product with 1 item. The only way to correctly calculate if swapping two price tags is beneficial is by looking at the old and new products of their qty and price.

Comment: @Lee: Each product has a certain quantity of stock. You place the price tag on the product, not each individual item. (If anyone can suggest better terminology or a better analogy entirely I'll gladly accept it)

Comment: @CyberShadow: maybe "shelf-mounted price label" rather than "price tag". I'm sure retailers have a term for those tags that sit under a clear plastic cover on the shelf, but I don't know what it is.

Comment: This problem smells suspiciously of NP...

Comment: What are typical values of N and K?  Over/under one million?

Comment: @CyberShadow, can you actually create a counterexample which shows that topological sort isn't enough?

Comment: @biziclop: of course it's NP, I think you mean NP-complete

Comment: @Peter @Steve: say you have products A, B, C, with the only constraint that TotalCost(A) < TotalCost(B).  There are 100 A, 2 B, and 1 C.  A topological sort (with a secondary sort by quantity) will give ABC - A receiving the cheapest price-tag, C receiving the most expensive.  If the price tags are $1, $75, and $150, this works; however, if the price tags are $1, $20, and $75, the constaint that TotalCost(A) < TotalCost(B) is broken - B *must* be given the most expensive price.  Thus, topological sort won't work - the solution *must* take into account the price-tags available!

Comment: I take it that `K < N!` is another constraint.

Comment: Bob should start a everything is $1 shop.

Comment: @BlueRaja - Danny Pflughoeft Are the constraints on the total costs or the individual price tags though?

Comment: Ah, ok, I've found a case where the greedy approach based on topological sort breaks. Stock: Ax1, Bx10, Cx2. Constraints: A<B. Prices: $1, $2, $3. Optimal solution: $27. But the initial open set is {A,C}, so C:=$1, A:=$2, B:=$3 for $34.

Comment: @Ron: N will be under 1 million, and K will be much lower. Still, in real-life the solution should preferably run in a fraction of a second. (N is the number of classes in a SWF file, K is the number of ancestor/derived class relationships between those classes.)

Comment: @biziclop: The constraints are on the price tags. I'll add the suggestions to the question now.

Comment: Gah, I realized I forgot to add an important detail: since ActionScript has no multiple inheritance, the graph formed by this adjacency list is actually a set of directed trees - no product may appear in B more than once.

Comment: @BlueRaja:  To escalate the nitpicking, the problem as stated isn't in NP.  Asking if there is a configuration with total price less than X is in NP, and that leads to a polynomially equivalent solution to the original problem.  It might be NP-hard.  A few minutes of casual thought has failed to produce a known NP-complete problem that reduces to this.

Comment: @David Thornley It was a joke comment anyway that it'll turn out to be NP-something-nasty.

Comment: If someone wants to try to prove this is NP-complete this other problem looks like a good target for a reduction: [link](http://www.csc.kth.se/~viggo/wwwcompendium/node120.html)

Comment: This can be modelled as an integer linear programming problem. I think that the matrix might be totally unimodular, so that an efficient general solution could be possible, but I have to admit that this goes over my head.

Comment: You can reduce each of the directed trees to a single sequence.  However, merging those does not have optimal substructure: the correct merge of two of these sequences is dependent on the available price tags and on the other sequences still not merged.

Comment: @CyberShadow: I think that the small number of available price tags should be taken into account, it severely reduces the number of different combinations. You could rephrase the way `Pj` are defined using a new constant `Q` indicating the number of different tags (and order the Pj).

Comment: is this for laying out a bunch of classes graphically?  Have you tried graphviz?

Comment: @Cybershadow, your new example is wrong. You say that the constraint is that item 10 must not be cheaper than item 1, but your "optimal solution" shows it being cheaper.

Comment: @Peter: I don't see how you came to that. In the example, the item with qty 10 is has the price 6, and the item with qty 1 has the price 5.

Comment: @Ron: no, ActionScript 3 bytecode uses variable-length integer encoding, and I'm looking to give classes indices so that the resulting file is as small as possible.

Comment: @Cybershadow, my mistake: I was reading the rows the wrong way round.

Comment: I find the phrase "There's at most one restriction for a product to be not cheaper than another" to be almost entirely unintelligible.  Firstly, the phrase "not cheaper than" is just a confusing form of "at least as expensive as".  Secondly, introducing names for the two products would help a lot.  How about: "For a given product P, there is at most one product Q for which P must be at least as expensive as Q."

Comment: I wanted to avoid symbolic notation in the prose part of the problem description. (The formal definition below already explains the restriction adequately, anyway.) Anyway, reworded that part, I think it sounds better now.

Comment: Asked on cstheory.SE: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/4932/bobs-sale-reordering-of-pairs-with-constraints-to-minimize-sum-of-products

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem is NP-complete for the general case. This can be shown via a reduction of 3-partition (which is a still strong NP-complete version of bin packing).

Let *w<sub>1</sub>, ..., w<sub>n</sub>* be the weights of objects of the 3-partition instance, let *b* be the bin size, and *k = n/3* the number of bins that are allowed to be filled. Hence, there is a 3-partition if objects can be partitioned such that there are exactly 3 objects per bin.

For the reduction, we set N=*kb* and each bin is represented by *b* price labels of the same price (think of P<sub>*i*</sub> increasing every *b*th label). Let *t<sub>i</sub>*, 1≤*i*≤*k*, be the price of the labels corresponding to the *i*th bin.
For each *w<sub>i</sub>* we have one product S<sub>*j*</sub> of quantity *w<sub>i</sub> + 1* (lets call this the root product of *w<sub>i</sub>*) and another *w<sub>i</sub> - 1* products of quantity 1 which are required to be cheaper than S<sub>*j*</sub> (call these the leave products).

For *t<sub>i</sub>* = (2b + 1)<sup>i</sup>, 1≤*i*≤*k*, there is a 3-partition if and only if Bob can sell for *2b*Σ<sub>1≤*i*≤*k*</sub> *t<sub>i</sub>*:

- If there is a solution for 3-partition, then all the *b* products corresponding to objects *w<sub>i</sub>*, *w<sub>j</sub>*, *w<sub>l</sub>* that are assigned to the same bin can be labeled with the same price without violating the restrictions.
  Thus, the solution has cost *2b*Σ<sub>1≤*i*≤*k*</sub> *t<sub>i</sub>* (since the total quantity of products with price *t<sub>i</sub>* is *2b*).

  Consider an optimal solution of Bob's Sale.
  First observe that in any solution were more than 3 root products share the same price label, for each such root product that is "too much" there is a cheaper price tag which sticks on less than 3 root products. This is worse than any solution were there are exactly 3 root products per price label (if existent).
  Now there can still be a solution of Bob's Sale with 3 root labels per price, but their leave products do not wear the same price labels (the bins sort of flow over).
  Say the most expensive price label tags a root product of *w<sub>i</sub>* which has a cheaper tagged leave product. This implies that the 3 root labels *w<sub>i</sub>*, *w<sub>j</sub>*, *w<sub>l</sub>* tagged with the most expensive price do not add up to *b*. Hence, the total cost of products tagged with this price is at least *2b+1*.
  Hence, such a solution has cost *t<sub>k</sub>(2b+1)* + some other assignment cost. Since the optimal cost for an existent 3-partition is *2b*Σ<sub>1≤*i*≤*k*</sub> *t<sub>i</sub>* , we have to show that the just considered case is worse. This is the case if *t<sub>k</sub> > 2b* Σ<sub>1≤*i*≤*k-1*</sub> *t<sub>i</sub>* (note that it's *k-1* in the sum now). Setting *t<sub>i</sub>* = (2b + 1)<sup>i</sup>, 1≤*i*≤*k*, this is the case. This also holds if not the most expensive price tag is the "bad" one, but any other.

So, this is the destructive part ;-) However, if the number of different price tags is a constant, you can use dynamic programming to solve it in polynomial time.

Answer (score 9):

This problem resembles many scheduling problems considered in the CS literature. Allow me to restate it as one.

**Problem** ("nonpreemptive single-machine scheduling with precedence, weights, and general lateness penalties")

Input:

- jobs 1, …, n
- a "treelike" precedence relation prec on the jobs (Hasse diagram is a forest)
- weights w<sub>1</sub>, …, w<sub>n</sub>
- a nondecreasing lateness penalty function L(t) from {1, …, n} to **Z**<sub>+</sub>

Output:

- a permutation π of {1, …, n} minimizing ∑<sub>j</sub> w<sub>j</sub> L(π(j)) subject to the constraints that for all i prec j we have π(i) < π(j).

Correspondence: job <=> product; i prec j <=> i has a lower price than j; weight <=> quantity; L(t) <=> t<sup>th</sup> lowest price

When L is linear, there is an efficient polynomial-time algorithm due to Horn [1].
The article is behind a pay wall, but the main idea is

1. For all j, find the connected set of jobs containing only j and its successors whose mean weight is maximum.
   For example, if n = 6 and the precedence constraints are 1 prec 2 and 2 prec 3 and 2 prec 4 and 4 prec 5, then the sets under consideration for 2 are
   {2}, {2, 3}, {2, 4}, {2, 3, 4}, {2, 4, 5}, {2, 3, 4, 5}.
   We actually only need the maximum mean weight, which can be computed bottom up by dynamic programming.
2. Schedule jobs greedily in order of the mean weight of their associated sets.

In CyberShadow's example, we have n = 10 and 1 prec 10 and w<sub>j</sub> = j and L(t) = t.
The values computed in Step 1 are

- job 1: 5.5 (mean of 1 and 10)
- job 2: 2
- job 3: 3
- job 4: 4
- job 5: 5
- job 6: 6
- job 7: 7
- job 8: 8
- job 9: 9
- job 10: 10

The optimal order is 9, 8, 7, 6, 1, 10, 5, 4, 3, 2.

---

This algorithm might work well in practice even for a different choice of L, as the proof of optimality uses local improvement.
Alternatively, perhaps someone on the CS Theory Stack Exchange will have an idea.

[1] W. A. Horn. *Single-Machine Job Sequencing with Treelike Precedence Ordering and Linear Delay Penalties*. SIAM Journal on Applied Mathematics, Vol. 23, No. 2 (Sep., 1972), pp. 189–202.

Comment: I'll admit that this is somewhat over my head, but nevertheless I'm not quite sure how to translate quantities and prices to weights and the lateness penalty function.

Comment: I still can't say I understand this completely (I expect to have to dive into the respective literature first), but are you stating that this algorithm should stand up to the issues brought up in the comments and posts below? For one, does the terms "greedy" and "local optimality" imply that it would stop trying in a direction if the next position is not an immediate improvement? I've posted (and just updated) a simple test case where this won't work (just for that part, but I imagine it can be expanded in either direction).

Comment: Another thing is that I don't see any explicit checks with regards to the sum of products between price and quantity. I have to assume that lateness and weight are multiplied to get the overall fitness in step 2?

Comment: There's no theoretical guarantee when L is not linear. The algorithm is greedy, but it's not a local search.

Comment: There's no multiply because L was assumed linear.

Comment: How do you determine the best way to order the jobs within the maximal set? Suppose {2, 3, 4} had the maximal mean weight, is it placed as (2,3,4) or as (2,4,3)?

Answer (score 4):

Since I thought the problem was fun, I did a model for finding solutions using constraint programming. The model is written in a modelling language called [MiniZinc](http://www.g12.csse.unimelb.edu.au/minizinc).

```
include "globals.mzn";

%%% Data declaration
% Number of products
int: n;
% Quantity of stock
array[1..n] of int: stock;
% Number of distinct price labels
int: m;
% Labels
array[1..m] of int: labels;
constraint assert(forall(i,j in 1..m where i < j) (labels[i] < labels[j]),
              "All labels must be distinct and ordered");
% Quantity of each label
array[1..m] of int: num_labels;
% Number of precedence constraints
int: k;
% Precedence constraints
array[1..k, 1..2] of 1..n: precedences;

%%% Variables
% Price given to product i
array[1..n] of var min(labels)..max(labels): prices :: is_output;
% Objective to minimize
var int: objective :: is_output;

%%% Constraints
% Each label is used once
constraint global_cardinality_low_up_closed(prices, labels, num_labels, num_labels);

% Prices respect precedences
constraint forall(i in 1..k) (
            prices[precedences[i, 1]] <= prices[precedences[i, 2]]
       );

% Calculate the objective
constraint objective = sum(i in 1..n) (prices[i]*stock[i]);

%%% Find the minimal solution
solve minimize objective;
```

Data for a problem is given in a separate file.

```
%%% Data definitions
n = 10;
stock = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
m = 10;
labels = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
num_labels = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1];
k = 1;
precedences = [| 1, 10 |];
```

The model is fairly naive and straight-forward, no fancy stuff. Using the [Gecode](http://www.gecode.org) back-end for solving the example problem, the following output is generated (assuming the model is in model.mzn and the data in data.dzn)

```
$ mzn2fzn -I/usr/local/share/gecode/mznlib/ model.mzn data.dzn
$ fz -mode stat -threads 0 model.fzn 
objective = 265;
prices = array1d(1..10, [1, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2]);
----------
objective = 258;
prices = array1d(1..10, [2, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 1, 3]);
----------
objective = 253;
prices = array1d(1..10, [3, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 2, 1, 4]);
----------
objective = 250;
prices = array1d(1..10, [4, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 3, 2, 1, 5]);
----------
objective = 249;
prices = array1d(1..10, [5, 10, 9, 8, 7, 4, 3, 2, 1, 6]);
----------
==========

%%  runtime:       0.027 (27.471000 ms)
%%  solvetime:     0.027 (27.166000 ms)
%%  solutions:     5
%%  variables:     11
%%  propagators:   3
%%  propagations:  136068
%%  nodes:         47341
%%  failures:      23666
%%  peak depth:    33
%%  peak memory:   237 KB
```

For larger problems it is of course much slower, but the model will typically generate successively better solutions over time.

Answer (score 3):

Posting some thoughts as a community wiki, feel free to edit.

This problem is easier to visualise if you think about the additional constraints as having to lay out or rearrange a set of top-to-bottom trees in such a way that *every node must be to the right of its parent* (products on the left are cheaper and those on the right are more expensive).

Let's say that two products are *conflicting* if the first has more stock than the second, and yet the first must not be cheaper than the other (so they are being "pulled" in different directions price-wise). Similarly, a conflicting group of products is one where at least two products are conflicting, and none of its products conflicts with any product outside the group.

We can make a few observations:

1. When "placing" (assigning a price tag to) two conflicting products, they will always be next to each other.
2. If you sort all products by quantity disregarding constraints, and then arrange them optimally so they satisfy the constraints, then the final positions of all products in a conflicting group will always be between (inclusively) the leftmost and rightmost initial positions of the products.
3. Therefore, if you can split a constraint tree in two by removing a single right-pointing edge from the tree such that the range of products' initial positions from the bottom subtree and the path to the tree root doesn't overlap, you can safely treat them as two distinct constraint trees (or single nodes) and forget that there was a dependency between them. ([simple example](http://dump.thecybershadow.net/0cc90ea12fa5dad579d89e5f4c9ae28a/aa.png))

An algorithm idea:

1. First, place all products not bound by restrictions.
2. For each constraint tree:

   1. Split it up into subtrees on all right-pointing edges (edges between non-conflicting products).
      We now have a set of subtrees with all edges pointing to the left.
   2. For each subtree:

      1. Get topologically-sorted list of it
      2. Try to insert this list at every position starting from the lowest to highest initial positions of the products in this subtree, settle on the one which yields lowest total price
   3. For each edge removed in step 2.1:

      1. If the new positions for two subtrees are "conflicting":

         1. Concatenate the higher with the lower list (special case of topological sort)
         2. Similarly try to find the optimal position for the concatenated list
         3. For future merging, consider the two examined subtrees as one subtree

The main problem with this algorithm is how to deal with displacement of already-placed constrained pairs. I imagine that simply trying to re-place displaced chains by iterative search might work, but the algorithm already looks too complicated to work right.

In the case that the number of distinct prices is low, you can use a deque (or doubly-linked list) for each distinct price, holding all the items with that price assigned to them. The deques are ordered from lowest to highest price. Inserting an item into a deque shifts the last item into the start of next deque (for the next higher distinct price), and so on for all deques after that.

One thing to note about iterative / bubble-sort-ish algorithms: when you have a conflicting pair of products, it is not enough to greedily walk in either direction by one position until the next one does not yield an improvement. Here is a test case I got by <s>[playing around a bit](http://dump.thecybershadow.net/f8d367dbf5e40cdd06d245aa2979433a/000006EC.png) with Mathematica</s> writing a [test case generator](http://ideone.com/k83Ws):

```
Price, $   1 2 7 9
Qty        3 2 1 4
```

The constraint is to have the 4-qty item to the right of the 1-qty item. As shown above, the total price is $50. If you move the pair one position to the left (so it's `3 1 4 2`), the total goes up to $51, but if you go once further (`1 4 3 2`) it goes down to $48.

Comment: I'm confused when you say "every node must be to the right of its parent" -- that would seem to remove the possibility of any left-pointing edges.  What does it mean for A to be the parent of B?  (I was assuming it meant "There is a constraint that product A must be assigned a lower price than product B".)

Comment: Yes, that's right. The part of my writeup that mentions trees with left-pointing edges imply before they are arranged to satisfy the constraints (product nodes are initially sorted by quantity).

Answer (score 3):

This is a follow-up on [Gero's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4898511/problem-bobs-sale/5020631#5020631).  The idea is to modify his construction to show strong NP-hardness.

Instead of choosing $t_i=(2b+1)^i$, chose $t_i=i$.  Now, you have to modify the argument that a solution with prize $P=2b\sum_{1\leq i \leq k} t_i$ implies that there exists a 3-partition.

Take an arbitrary shelf order.  Do the accounting in the following way: distribute $w_i-1$ units of quantity of the root-product to its leaf-products.  Then every product has quantity 2.  By definition of the constraints, this does not shift to a higher price.
After this shifting, the price will be exactly $P$.
If the shifting moved some quantity to a lower prize, the original prize was strictly larger than $P$.

Hence, it is only possible to achieve the claimed prize, if all leaf-products have the same prize as their root-product, which means that there exists a 3-partition.

Citing the result from a [SWAT 2010 paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-13731-0_25) this argument shows that even with unary encoding of the numbers and $k$ different price tags, a running time of $f(k)\cdot n^{O(1)}$ would violate "standard complexity assumptions".
This makes the hinted at dynamic programming with a running time of $n^{O(k)}$ look not so bad.

---

This is cross-posted from the same [answer](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/4932/bobs-sale-reordering-of-pairs-with-constraints-to-minimize-sum-of-products/4968#4968) at cstheory.

Answer (score 1):

You could try first solving the simpler case where you simply have to sort labels by price and products by quantity, and match both directly, and then use an evolutionary process on this first approximation: generate random variations of the ordered list of products that you have, shifting a small number of random selected items up or down the list just a few places, calculate the total cost of each variation on the list, keep the best few and make those the basis of your next generation. Iterating this process over a number of generations should eventually, I expect, give you the right answer to your problem, in a fraction of the time it would take to brute force the solution.

Comment: Generational algorithms will suffer from local minimum problems (see my community wiki post).

Answer (score 1):

One way to attack the problem is to express it using [0-1 linear programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming#Integer_unknowns) and solve it using Balas' Additive Algorithm.  Here's how the problem could be encoded:

- **Variables:**  **N<sup>2</sup>** binary variables.  For the sake of clarity I will index them by two integers: **x<sub>ij</sub>** is **1** if and only if product **i** is assigned label **j**.
- **Objective function:** minimize sum over **i** and **j** of **S<sub>i</sub>P<sub>j</sub>x<sub>ij</sub>** (represents the original objective function).
- **Constraint:** for each **k** sum over **j** of **P<sub>j</sub>x<sub>A<sub>k</sub>j</sub> – P<sub>j</sub>x<sub>B<sub>k</sub>j</sub>** is **≤ 0** (represents the original price constraints).
- **Constraints:** for each **i** sum over **j** of **x<sub>ij</sub>** is **1**; for each **j** sum over **i** of **x<sub>ij</sub>** is **1** (says that **x** encodes a permutation).

I'm not an expert in linear programming, probably there exists a more efficient encoding.

Comment: @Bolo- 0-1 linear programming in NP-hard, right?  So this would be just a good, optimized way to tackle the problem using a solver that in worst-case won't be in polynomial time?

Comment: @templatetypedef: the complexity of linear programming problems is often pessimistic.

Comment: @templatetypedef Right.  If this problem is in P, then a relevant polynomial algorithm will surely outperform the 0-1 linear programming solution.  However, if the problem is not in P (which I suspect is the case), then linear programming should be a reasonable approach, since it has been studied for over half a century and the solvers are often quite fast *in practice*.

Answer (score 0):

**Generate the permutations of the prices in lexicographic order**, and return the first one that fits the constraints.

Assuming products and prices are already sorted (fewest to most, and highest to lowest, respectively),

1. Set `l[k] = k+1` for `0 <= k < n` and `l[n] = 0`.  Then set `k = 1`.
2. Set `p = 0, q = l[0]`.
3. Set `M[k] = q`.  If any price constraint specifically involving `P[k]` fails, go to 5.  Otherwise, if `k = n`, return `M[1]...M[n]`.
4. Set `u[k] = p, l[p] = l[q], k = k + 1` and go to 2.
5. Set `p = q, q = l[p]`.  If `q != 0` go to 3.
6. Set `k = k - 1`, and terminate if `k = 0`.  Otherwise, set `p = u[k], q = M[k], l[p] = q` and go to 5.

This is (a slight modification of) Algorithm X from Knuth's Art of Computer Programming, Volume 4, Fascicle 2, Section 7.2.1.2.  As with most of Knuth's algorithms, it uses 1-based indexing.  Hacking it to fit the 0-based indexing of your typical programming language I leave as an exercise for the reader.

**Edit:**

Unfortunately, it turns out that this doesn't guarantee a non-decreasing sequence.  I'll have to give it more thought to see if this can be salvaged.

Comment: Will this work correctly given that the quantities are not all the same?

Comment: It should.  If you think about it, the best possible solution is one where the product with the lowest numbers in inventory gets the highest price, and then so on down the list with each product with increasing numbers getting a lower price.  Permuting the price mapping in lexicographic order, then, will find progressively higher cost solutions with no reversals.

Comment: How will that scale to N items with potentially many price constraints?